# Given $|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|^3$, is $f$ increasing, decreasing or constant?

Tags: calculus, functions

For all $x,y\in (0,\infty)$, a function $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies the inequality $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le|x-y|^3.$$ Then is $f$ increasing, decreasing or a constant function?

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: Hint. What happens if you try to compute the derivative of $f$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\left|\frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x - y}\right| \leq |x-y|^2
$$
This shows us something about the derivative (which, in turn, must exist).

Comment: Thanks! To solve it completely,
$|f'(x)|=\lim_{y\to x}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\le \lim_{y\to x}|x-y|^2=0 \implies f'(x)=0 \forall x\in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: @ponderlust exactly!

Answer (score 0):

If $x \not =y$, $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq |x-y|^{2}$. Fix $y$, and let $x \to y$, by squeeze,$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|} \to 0$ and hence so does $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$, and so the derivative is zero, at any point